# Can't run .exe files compiled with gcc (minGW)

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, msys

I have this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int courses = 1, groups, students = 54, average_pr_group;

    /* The variable groups is uninitialized */

    average_pr_group = students / groups;

    printf("Groups: %d\n", groups);

    printf("There are %d students pr. group in %d course(s)\n", average_pr_group, courses);

    return 0;
}
```

Now i compile this using this command from the shell (cmd):

```
gcc test.c -o test.exe -lm -Wall
```

It compiles fine, but when I try to run the generated .exe through Windows Explorer I get this error:
[image: Error running .exe file compiled with gcc]

In contrast, I can compile & run this piece of code just fine:

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

I have MinGW installed at C:\MinGW
This is my user PATH variable:
[image: User path variable]

I can run the .exe just fine with msys, is it just built to withstand those kind of errors?

Comment: Your code is crashing.  You haven't initialized `groups` and it's probably zero and you're dividing by 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `groups` is probably zero, therefore you divide by zero:

```
average_pr_group = students / groups;
```

Comment: `groups` is uninitialized doesn't implies it has zero value.

Comment: Yes, it depends on used standard and compiler. Therefore I wrote "probably", as author did not provided such information. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: so far I know, there's nothing in the C standard says locals should be zero value as default but that accessing them is UB. And I didn't know there are compilers that does defaults to 0 uninitialized variables.

Comment: Older versions of GCC (like 4.4) defaulted integers to zero without initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

as variable groups is uninitialized it has a undefined or garbage value and that's why the program is crashing...dividing by an uninitialized variable leads to crashing......